# Dont apply hover effect to parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the color of the div, over which the mouse cursor is. But only one element, I dont want to apply the new color to the parent elements.

I tried this, but I have no idea, how to solve this.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>d</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    e
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lurwp7ey/

Comment: use js seems to be the solution

Comment: he is trying to achive stop propagation in css :D

Comment: You might need to wait for CSS4.

Comment: no problem. I will use javascript then

Comment: you can add class for divs that you want to change their colors on hover. then select them in your css based on their class names.

Comment: This happens in non IE browsers, am I correct?

Comment: @Sunand and how is `stopPropagation` going to solve the issue?  How can you get inside the child elements in the layout without triggering `mouseenter` in parent? do you see `padding:5px; border:1px solid;`?

Comment: @TJ Sorry, I didnt mean the exact thing. I referring its some thing similar like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, here it is:

```
$(".not_parent").hover(function(e){
    $(this).css("background-color","green");
    e.stopPropagation();
    },function(e){
    $(this).css("background-color","white");
        e.stopPropagation();
  });

<div>
    <div class="not_parent">a</div>
    <div class="not_parent">b</div>
    <div>
        <div class="not_parent">c</div>
        <div class="not_parent">d</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="not_parent">
    e
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lurwp7ey/3/

@chris's solution is better, use jquery only if you would want additional effects.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this.

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="c">a</div>
<div class="c">b</div>
<div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
    <div class="c">d</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="c">
e
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.c:hover {
    background: green;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lurwp7ey/2/).

Answer (score 1):

CSS4 will use an exclamation point to allow styling of a parent element -- with CSS4 add one rule. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/

```
div {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
div:hover {
    background: green;
}
div! div { /* if a div contains a div apply this rule to parent div*/
    background: white;
}
```

And there is a lib that already supports it on browsers that do not come from the future.

```
<script src="jQuery.cssParentSelector.js"></script>
```